# Translation of default folder names in Windows

Tags: windows, localization

Windows (all versions) folders have their standard names such as Users, Documents, Local Settings etc that are unfortunately translated in other language versions, and thus instead of the names that are in the path to the folder they appear in the file explorer under quite different names. For example, instead Pictures I get "Moje obrazy" (translation into Polish language), and yet in the path it is still "pictures".

This is very confusing and I would like to turn this automatic translation off, but can't find how.

Answer (score 0):

This is because one is a generic library name and the other is the physical path. You could set the library path to include other directories (see properties on the library). Windows is attempting to show you the library in a localized name. The only way to change it is to change the OS language.